# onDragOver very slow with Angular Material tabs

Tags: drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular6

I'm using Angular 6 and Angular Material. I'm attempting to implement a simple drag and drop list inside of a Material tab (). Drag and drop works fine outside of a material tab, but inside the tab it's very slow (18 seconds to DnD 1 item in a list of 5 items). The onDragEvent fires many many times even when the mouse isn't moving. I've tried detaching (onDragStart) and reattaching (onDrop) the change detector. It doesn't make a difference.

Here's the html:

```
<div (dragover)="onDragOver($event)">
    <div *ngFor="let item of listItems, let i = index"
         (drop)="onDrop($event, i)"
         [draggable]="true"
         (dragstart)="onDragStart(i)">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are the functions:

```
onDragStart(i) {
}


onDragOver(event) {
    console.log('1')
    event.preventDefault();
}

onDrop(event, i) {
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was experiencing a similar issue, where dragging when there were many elements on the page was unbearably slow. I found that removing the (dragover) angular binding, and replacing it with pure javascript instantly solved the problem

i switched

```
(dragover)="this.onDragOver($event)"
```

to

```
ondragover="onDragOver(event)"
```

you also need to declare the function in index.html instead of in your typescript file or html template (hence pure javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your suggestion, but got this error: Uncaught TypeError: this.allowDrop is not a function.

Comment: sorry - your function is named onDragOver, not allowDrop. I have edited my original response to reflect that change

Comment: The function name isn't the issue. I'd changed my code to alloDrop, after i'd tried using my original name (onDragOver).    
   
Same error: Uncaught ReferenceError: onDragOver is not defined at HTMLDivElement.ondragover ((index):1)   
   
The call i'm currently using is <div ondragover="onDragOver(event)">   
   
The method is the component is: onDragOver(event) {
        event.preventDefault();  }

Comment: where is the function defined? i updated the answer to include that pure js functions have to be placed in the index.html file inside a script tag. If its inside an html template or the typescript it will be inaccessible

Comment: works beautifully! thank you for walking me through it.

Comment: glad to hear it! feel free to upvote the answer and mark as best answer so other people can find it too

Answer (score 3):

It appears that as I dragged the item around the screen- even briefly, the Angular engine was overfiring and queuing up a ridiculous number of calls of onDrop and/or onDragEnter. And that when angular hooks those events, it also assumes that something in the angular components has changed and it runs through the change detection routines.

Each... time.

What I did that fixed my problem was to turn off change detection when dragging began and turn it back on when dragging was complete.

Here is a brief hint at what I did:

1. import `ChangeDetectorRef from '@angular/core'`
2. inject ChangeDetector into your constructor: 
         `constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef)`
3. call detach from the dragStart:
         `this.cdr.detach();`
4. call reattach from the drop and dragEnd:
         `this.cdr.reattach();`

If your component is buried deep on your page, you may have to detach change detection at a higher level in order to see results.

Comment: Almost 4 years later this post is giving me more relief than you can imagine. Thanks!